# where are the circuitikz keys located within a miktex install?

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, circuitikz

I am looking for the circuitikz source files in my miktex installation (Windows 7) so I can Use the Source to determine which scaling factors do what. (since there isn't really any specific documentation)

How can I find the source files within my miktex install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, never mind, it looks like MiKTeX installs stuff in `c:\Users\{myusername}\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\circuitikz`

I was looking at the directory where I installed MiKTeX.

Comment: The answers depends on whether you made an installation for all users (as administrator) or a  personal installation.

Answer (score 1):

Why not take a look at the git-repo of the developers?
https://github.com/mredaelli/circuitikz

The values are defined in the file:
https://github.com/mredaelli/circuitikz/blob/master/tex/pgfcirc.defines.tex
(For versions <0.5 this file was called circuitikz.code.tex)

The shapes you will find in the other files, mainly pgfcircbipoles for path elements,pgfcirctripoles for transistors, and pgfcircquadpoles for opamps.

PS: We will try to document these values in the near future

Comment: point taken -- if you can be more specific I'll upvote and accept.

Comment: @JMP This may not answer the title question, but it is a good answer to the question posed in the body of the post (i.e., where can I look at the source files of CircuiTikz).